# Python basemap - struggling with putting a basemap on top of a satellite image

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy, geography

I have a satellite image taken from NWC-SAF of a certain region of the world, and 2 ndarrays that holds data about the latitudes and longitudes values of each pixel.

I try to use this information and mpl_toolkits.basemap package to accurately add land and Maritime borders to the image.

This is the script i used to build the basemap:

```
def add_basemap(foreground_dimensions: tuple[int, int], low_left_corner_lat, low_left_corner_lon, upper_right_corner_lat, upper_right_corner_lon, dpi):
    """
    Given a satellite image and its coordinates (corners' latitudes & longitudes), Add borders and coastlines
    """
    plt.clf()
    width, height = foreground_dimensions[0], foreground_dimensions[1]
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width / (dpi), height / (dpi)), dpi=dpi)
    map_figure = Basemap(projection='cyl',
                         llcrnrlat=low_left_corner_lat,
                         llcrnrlon=low_left_corner_lon,
                         urcrnrlat=upper_right_corner_lat,
                         urcrnrlon=upper_right_corner_lon,
                         resolution='i',
                         )

    fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1)
    plt.axis('tight')
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.margins(0)
    map_figure.drawcoastlines(linewidth=dpi / 8)
```

foreground_dimensions are the dimensions of the satellite image.

the result that i get is not accurate:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTFCT.png)

the green is the land and blue is water and as you can see the map does not fit accurately on the image.

I guess that the problem is projection differences - i use satallite image from NWC-SAF, which if i understood correctly from their website, they use "polar stereographic, map-projection". I think that the correspond projection in Basemap is either 'npstere' or 'spstere', so i tried using them, creating the following basemap:

```
map_figure = Basemap(projection='npstere', boundinglat=max_lat, lon_0=middle_lon, resolution='l')
```

where biggest_lat is the max latitude value that appears in the satellite picture, and middle_lon is the longitude value of the middle pixel of the satellite picture.

But this gives a map that doesn't make any sense (unlike the previous map i generated which correlates to the original image but not accurate).

How can i generate an accurate map? using Basemap or maybe cartopy?

Thanks